# Net Core API: Purpose of ProducesResponseType

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to understand the purpose of `ProducesResponseType.`

Microsoft defines as:

> a filter that specifies the type of the value and status code returned by the action.

So I am curious what are consequences if

- a person does not place ProductResponseType?
- How is system at a disadvantage, or is there negative consequence?
- Doesn't Microsoft API already automatically inherently know the type/value of status code returned?

```
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(DepartmentDto), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
```

Documentation from the Microsoft: [ProducesResponseTypeAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesresponsetypeattribute?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Comment: As far as I'm aware, it's purely documentation. If you use a tool like NSwag or Swashbuckle, it will show possible responses to endpoints based on this attribute. I'm not aware of any effect it has outside of producing API documentation.

Comment: @ChrisPratt feel free to post as answer, and I can send points, thanks !

Comment: I'm not sure it is *the* answer. Someone else might know something I don't. I've just never seen the attribute in any discussion that didn't involve API documentation. That doesn't mean it doesn't actually have some other purpose.

Comment: Look for my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72063833/2110597), some reflection tricks can be used to do not only documentation but also for runtime checking (testing for example).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think it can come handy for non-success (200) return codes.
Say if one of the failure status codes returns a model that describes the problem, you can specify that the status code in that case produces something different than the success case.
You can read more about that and find examples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: quote from that linked page "This attribute produces more descriptive response details for web API help pages generated by tools like Swagger." so I guess it's for documentation purposes (and possibly could be used by static code analysis).

Comment: Looks like more cruft. If boilerplate XML comments didn't clutter up your code enough for your liking, now there's this. Boy, it sure looks smart in the text editor, though!

Answer (score 70):

Although the correct answer is already submitted, I would like to provide an example. Assume you have added the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package to your project, and have used it in Startup.Configure(...) like this:

```
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
{
    options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My Web Service API V1");
    options.RoutePrefix = "api/docs";  

});
```

Having a test controller action endpoint like this:

```
[HttpGet]        
public ActionResult GetAllItems()
{
    if ((new Random()).Next() % 2 == 0)
    {
        return Ok(new string[] { "value1", "value2" });
    }
    else
    {
        return Problem(detail: "No Items Found, Don't Try Again!");
    }
}
```

Will result in a swagger UI card/section like this (Run the project and navigate to /api/docs/index.html):

[image]

As you can see, there is no 'metadata' provided for the endpoint.

Now, update the endpoint to this:

```
[HttpGet]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<string>), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(404)]
public ActionResult GetAllItems()
{
    if ((new Random()).Next() % 2 == 0)
    {
        return Ok(new string[] { "value1", "value2" });
    }
    else
    {
        return Problem(detail: "No Items Found, Don't Try Again!");
    }
}
```

This won't change the behavior of your endpoint at all, but now the swagger page looks like this:

[image]

This is much nicer, because now the client can see what are the possible response status codes, and for each response status, what is the type/structure of the returned data.
Please note that although I have not defined the return type for 404, but ASP.NET Core (I'm using .NET 5) is smart enough to set the return type to [ProblemDetails](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.problemdetails?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

If this is the path you want to take, it's a good idea to add the [Web API Analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/analyzers?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) to your project, to receive some useful warnings.

p.s. I would also like to use **options.DisplayOperationId();** in app.UseSwaggerUI(...) configuration. By doing so, swagger UI will display the name of the actual .NET method that is mapped to each endpoint. For example, the above endpoint is a GET to /api/sample but the actual .NET method is called  GetAllItems()

Comment: For controllers that return a ordinary type rather than an ActionResult, could/should there a be way to have Swagger automatically infer that the C# return type is for the success/200 and thus not have to add these redundant `[ProducesResponseType(typeof(...), 200)]` attributes on every controller method?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski I believe you can use compile-time code injectors, like https://github.com/Fody/Fody to avoid bloating your code with repeated attributes. I'm almost certain there are some Roslyn compilation services / code generation features, capable of achieving something similar, e.g. mark the controller class and action method as 'partial', then generate a partial class for it with partial method declarations that are decorated with all the required attributes. (I have not done this myself, just thinking aloud! LOL)

Comment: Hii Sivasah, Your answer was so useful. I have another doubt is it possible to have two [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<UserDto>), 200)] and [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<MemberDto>), 200)] for a single constructor method?.Can we define it dynamically?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski You'd think so, right? It does that if, and unfortunately only if, you do not document any error responses. But if you don't document your error responses, then `ProblemDetails` isn't included in the schema...

Comment: @ThomasRaj You mean action method, not constructor, right? Regardless of its possibility, I think it's not a good design decision. E.g. If your endpoint is /api/users/{id}, it's very ambiguous to return either a UserDto or a MemberDto object, based on some internal logic, and don't forget you have to cast it Object or something. I would suggest to use the concept of the "view model", e.g. a model dedicated to return an object to a particular view/endpoint and always return objects of that type. p.s. Its totally fine to leave some properties alone and configure the JSON serializer to leave them

Answer (score 12):

It's for producing Open API metadata for API exploration/visualization tools such as Swagger (https://swagger.io/), to indicate in the documentation what the controller may return.

Answer (score 0):

## SwaggerResponse and ProducesResponseType attributes checking

You can use [this extension](https://gist.github.com/PROGrand/018aff221ed7a87992e0925815147381#file-swaggerresponsevalidator-cs) in dotnet (.NET 6 in my case) for enforcing developers to
sync OpenAPI (Swagger) descriptions with implementations of methods.

### 3 different usage choices

#### Across all app controllers:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
        app.UseSwaggerResponseCheck();
  //...
}
```

#### Per controller action using ValidateStatusCodes attribute:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [ValidateStatusCodes] // <-- Use this
    [SwaggerOperation("LoginUser")]
    [SwaggerResponse(statusCode: StatusCodes.Status200OK, type: null, description: "signed user email account")]
    [SwaggerResponse(statusCode: StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, type: null, description: "wrong email or password")]
    [Route("/users/login")]
    public virtual IActionResult LoginUser([FromQuery][Required()] string email, [FromQuery] string password)
    {
            if (email == "email@gmail.com")
              return Ok("success");
            else if (email == "")
              return BadRequest("email required");
            else
              return NotFound("user not found"); // 500 - InternalServerError because not attributed with SwaggerResponse.
    }
    // ...
    [HttpGet]
    [ValidateStatusCodes] // <-- Use this
    [ProducesResponseType(type: typeof(Account), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [Route("/users/login2")]
    public virtual IActionResult LoginUser2([FromQuery][Required()] string email, [FromQuery] string password)
    {
            if (email == "email@gmail.com")
              return Ok("success").Validate();
            else if (email == "")
              return BadRequest("email required").Validate();
            else
              return NotFound("user not found").Validate(); // Throws error in DEBUG or Development.
    }
}
```

#### Per result using IStatusCodeActionResult.Validate():

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [SwaggerOperation("LoginUser")]
    [SwaggerResponse(statusCode: StatusCodes.Status200OK, type: null, description: "signed user email account")]
    [SwaggerResponse(statusCode: StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest, type: null, description: "wrong email or password")]
    [Route("/users/login")]
    public virtual IActionResult LoginUser([FromQuery][Required()] string email, [FromQuery] string password)
    {
            if (email == "email@gmail.com")
              return Ok("success").Validate();
            else if (email == "")
              return BadRequest("email required").Validate();
            else if (email == "secret")
              return Unauthorized("hello");
                 // Passed, independent of SwaggerResponse attribute.
            else
              return NotFound("user not found").Validate();
                 // 500 - InternalServerError because not attributed with SwaggerResponse.
    }
    // ...
    [HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(type: typeof(Account), StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
    [Route("/users/login2")]
    public virtual IActionResult LoginUser2([FromQuery][Required()] string email, [FromQuery] string password)
    {
            if (email == "email@gmail.com")
              return Ok("success").Validate();
            else if (email == "")
              return BadRequest("email required").Validate();
            else
              return NotFound("user not found").Validate(); // Throws error in DEBUG or Development.
    }
}
```